# how to get object from spring service in angular controller?

Tags: html, angularjs, spring

the service is working on spring But when
i try to call a service in angular , the result object is empty and nothing is returned

service code :

public class CalculatorController {

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8090")
@GetMapping("/calc/{number1}/{number2}")
public Calculator calc(@PathVariable int number1, 
            @PathVariable int number2){
        Calculator c = new Calculator(number1 , number2) ;
    return c;
}
```

}

controller js code :

```html
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope , $http) {
     $http.get('http://localhost:8090/calc/5/8').
     then(function (response)
       { $scope.result = response.data; }) ;
     
    });
```

html code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
  <script src="moule.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <p><span class="add">add is {{ result.add }}</span></p>
 <span class="sub">sub is {{ result.sub }}</span>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Your client and server side are on different ports (different projects)?

Comment: sorry post is edited

Comment: yea it is different

Comment: what should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CORS filter (`@CrossOrigin`) is set to `http://localhost:8090` but seems like this is where your server side code reside. CORS should allow a source outside of your server to query your API, that means you need to provide your client side port information.

Lets say your server side runs on `8090` and your client on `8080`. Your filter on the server side should allow `8080` to use the API from a browser.

Try to change the CORS filter to match your client side not the server side.

Also, look in chrome debug tools (`F12`) to see if you have a CORS exception.

More information about CORS:

1. [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
2. [Understanding CORS](https://spring.io/understanding/CORS)
3. [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: `@CrossOrigin` annotation is used to allow CORS - `cross-origin resource sharing`. A browser won't allow you to use an API outside of your domain unless it is allowed by CORS filter to access it. So that means if your client side is running on port `8080` and you try to query your server side code on port `8090` and the server does not return the right CORS headers, it will be droped and an exception will be shown in your browser console stating there is a CORS error.

Comment: the server of angular work on port 8060 .. 
and the server of service work on port 8090..
what should i do now ??

Comment: change `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8090")` to `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8060")` and make sure you have no errors in your browser console. If you do, please add them to your question.

Comment: I change It But still same problem

Comment: It seems like a CORS problem, please add the error from your browser console if there is any.

Comment: there is no errors in browser console .. browser page : 
add is

sub is

mult is

div is

Comment: There are no errors both before and after the change of the `@CrossOrigin` annotation?

Comment: yea there is no difference

Comment: i restarted IDE and Run it again and It Work .. 
iam very sorry for your time and thank you very much

Comment: did you add `@ResponseBody` or not?

Comment: yea i have added it

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this. you forgot add `@ResponseBody`
 annotation for your method

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8090")
@GetMapping("/calc/{number1}/{number2}")
@ResponseBody
 public Calculator calc(@PathVariable("number1") int number1, 
        @PathVariable("number2") int number2){
    Calculator c = new Calculator(number1 , number2) ;
 return c;
}
}
```

Comment: compiler tell me ..
The annotation @RequestBody is disallowed for this location

Comment: sorry. i fixed it. `@ResponseBody`

Comment: this does not fix problem .. still object is empty

Comment: as @Tom  said you should change to this `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8060")` too

Comment: I change It But still same problem

Comment: why you add twice `ng-app` and `ng-controller`? and what display in console?

Comment: I deleted the repetition .. as expected >>result object will has four variables